# ajax file upload for specific number of input

Tags: php, ajax, upload

```
<form class="imagegen_file" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/image_maker/file">
<input class="file" name="image_0" type="file">
<input class="file" name="image_1" type="file">
<input class="file" name="image_2" type="file">
<input class="file" name="image_3" type="file">
<input .....
</form>

<a onclick="return image_gen_file();">upload</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function image_gen_file(){
    var data = new FormData();
    jQuery.each($('.file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        data.append('image_'+i, file);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl + "/image_maker/file",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });

}</script>
```

guys for the above code file upload works for only 1st input ("image_0") i want to get it works for all others how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only looping over the first `input`. You need a nested loop:

```
var data = new FormData();

$('.file').each(function(i) {
    $.each(this.files, function(j) {
        data.append('image_' + i + '_' + j, this);
    });
});
```

---

If you want to post them each in their own AJAX post, use this instead:

```
$('.file').each(function() {

    var data = new FormData();

    jQuery.each(this.files, function(i, file) {
        data.append('image_'+i, file);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl + "/image_maker/file",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i would like to post them all at once.. and `$('.file').each(function()` code only output single array of (image_0)

Comment: @RajeshDante - I don't get it. In the first method I showed you, `data` will contain *all* images in the form!

Comment: [link](http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/3194/76590988.png) check that link i selected 3 images but it showing only one image

Comment: @RajeshDante - That was my fault. I wasn't using the index of the outer loop. I added it now. Try it.

Comment: can i able to add id in data? like this `data: data + "&id=123",`

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = new FormData();
$('.file').each(function(i) {
    data.append('file'+i, this.files[0]);
});
$.ajax({
    url: baseurl + "/image_maker/file",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```